# Spring integration claim-check pattern - resend on failure

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-amqp

So, my setup is:

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="input-channel" queue-names="probni" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"
                                  channel-transacted="true"
                                  transaction-manager="dataSourceTransactionManager"/>
<int:chain input-channel="input-channel" output-channel="oc2">
    <int:service-activator ref="h1" method="handle" />
    <int:service-activator ref="h2" method="handle" />
    <int:service-activator ref="h3" method="handle" />
    <int:splitter  />
    <int:claim-check-in message-store="messageStore" />
</int:chain>


<int:channel id="oc2">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="oc3" />

<int:claim-check-out message-store="messageStore" input-channel="oc2" output-channel="oc3" auto-startup="true" remove-message="true" />

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter exchange-name="someexc" channel="oc3" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" />
```

I want to be able to store message to messageStore in same transaction as int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter, and then have separate thread that will actually send this message to other amqp exchange. Also, if first thread saves the message in messageStore and then complete process is killed, on restart claim-check-out should know that it needs to load unsent message and send it to oc3 channel in this case.

One more thing  - if I have multiple claim-check-in/out workers sharing the same DB table, how they know which message is belonging to which claim-check-out worker (especially important when we have multiple messages from different claim-check-in's on component start)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's take a look to the Claim-Check description one more time:

> In the above configuration the Message that is received on the `input-channel` will be persisted to the Message Store identified with the `message-store` attribute and indexed with generated ID. That ID is the Claim Check for that Message. The Claim Check will also become the payload of the new (transformed) Message that will be sent to the `output-channel`.

So, after transforming in the Claim-Check-In we have an `id` for the stored message and that is used by the Claim-Check-Out to restore a stored message.

You can use `QueueChannel` instead of executor with persistent `MessageStore` for that purpose.

That is one idea.

Another is like really poll `INT_MESSAGE` table via regular `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` for the `MESSAGE_ID` column and send the results to the `<claim-check-out>`.

Comment: So claim-check-out has no default poller? Also, it seems that if i have two claim-check-in components, i need also 2 message stores (possibly 2 dofferent jdbc schemas) to differentiate messages if some failure occurs? Other option is to enrich headers with additional info?

Comment: Your concern isn't clear. That Claim-Check is `transformer`. Please, read its manual carefully. It isn't Claim-Check responsibility to poll the DB. No, you don't need to have several messageStores or tables. Each message has its own unique ID. That is fully enough for differentiating. As I said: you can send message with the claim-check id to the persistent QueueChannel and supply its poller with the transaction do not lose such message. Please, do not mix concerns. Spring Integration components are loosely-coupled and perform their particular role.

Comment: The use-case i needed is actually in 1st thread to consume amqp message, process it and save outgoing message in db and after this i notify second thread that there are messages in db. At same time other thread is waiting for this notification and at the same time polling db for messages (just in case). If message is found, it reads message, sends to amqp and deletes the message. Maybe db backed-up spring integration queue is better in this case?

Comment: Right, that fully looks like QueueChannel stuff with DB-backed MessageStore. OTOH it isn't clear why you have to store message in the DB if AMQP Broker is good place to keep persistence and don't worry about message loss.

Comment: I'm worried about message loss in between db save and amqp send. Since rabbit has no XA i make sure this way that msgs are not lost if process dies. Amqp receiver is bound to db transaction.

Comment: No, you good there just with regular TX. The message is acked on Rabbit Broker only in the end of TX. You don't need to worry about XA there.

Comment: Yes, as far as i understood I have to worry only about duplicate messages.

Comment: I forgot to ask - since queue that is jdbc backed-up is polling each X ms, is it possible to beside polling have it also push messages on demand down the pipeline? Some workaround to simulate this kind of behavior?

Comment: That is what `max-messages-per-poll` on the `<polled>` does

Comment: Just checked this config but this is not it - this setting is no of mesages in 1 poll. I need basically, if i set poller interval to 10sec (not to overload the backing db) and message arrives just after poll is done (and queue is now sleeping) i need to wait ~9 seconds for message to be pushed down the pipeline. Is there som way to wakeup poller on message arival?

Comment: No, because you need some how know to know that message is in the db. You can know that only polling it.

Comment: But other thread has just put the message in queue. So I'm sure that message must be there. Something like proces1-> queue and at same time notify process2 that it can expect smth. In queue.

Comment: Use recipient-list-router with the direct channel as second recipient. Than use some conditional polling advice to resume to poll from queue